# Git on Windows: Why I suddenly have untracked directory that used to be tracked?

Tags: windows, git

When i hit 'git status', it shows 2 folders that contains files that are tracked long time ago:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       src/UI/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/
#       src/Web/helpers/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Git GUI shows nothing as expected.

Using [portablegit 1.7.1](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list), but tried 1.7.0.2 - same results.

What can cause that?

---

```
$ cat .gitignore
.nu/*
lib/*
*~
*.swp
*.swo
*_ReSharper*
doc/*
RAPLM.suo
RAPLM.5.1.ReSharper.user
src/*/bin/*
src/*/obj/*
src/*/Debug/*
src/*/Release/*
src/Domain/unused
```

---

@Charles Bailey

```
lapsaarn@WW021198 /d/work/asdf (master)
$ git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       src/UI/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/
#       src/Web/helpers/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

lapsaarn@WW021198 /d/work/asdf (master)
$ git add src/Web/helpers/

lapsaarn@WW021198 /d/work/asdf (master)
$ git add src/Web/helpers/*

lapsaarn@WW021198 /d/work/asdf (master)
$ git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       src/UI/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/
#       src/Web/helpers/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

lapsaarn@WW021198 /d/work/asdf (master)
$
```

---

@Charles

> $ git ls-tree -r HEAD | grep -i helpers
>   100644 blob 843de27f850308786140a7c09f67b5ef99184630   src/web/helpers/HtmlHelperExtensions.cs

Comment: take a look at your .gitignore file.

Comment: @adamk I did. what changed? :/

Comment: @Arnis: It was a hunch, I guess it isn't it...

Comment: What makes you think that git lies? Those paths may have been tracked a long time ago, but they're not tracked now.

Comment: @Charles updated my question. Another thing as i wrote already - Git GUI show nothing as expected.

Comment: I'll take a wild guess. You're working on a case insensitive file system. What does `git ls-tree -r HEAD | grep -i helpers` show?

Comment: @Charles I am working on case insensitive file system. So - what is actually going on here?

Comment: In your repository you have a folder called `src/web` but on your file system it's called `src/Web`. I'd pick one and stick to it. Either use lower case on your file system or change the one in your repository to use an initial capital.

Comment: @Arnis L. Inflammatory question title isn't really necessary - I'll read any git question posted here, and I expect the usual git experts do the same.

Comment: @Jefromi I thought that would reflect better how it **seems** to **me**. It's me who got problem not Git itself. I don't think it's so hard to distinguish that. Anyway - I'm thankful that my issue is fixed, still waiting on @Charles to post an answer.

Comment: @Arnis L. Eh, fair enough, I guess. Mostly just wanted to let you know you don't need any bait to attract some good attention.

Comment: Um... I'm confused. Why do I need to post an answer? I thought we'd solved (or at least diagnosed) the issue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Charles Bailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19563/charles-bailey) correctly diagnosed the problem in the comments: "`git add`" on a case insensitive Os.

It is linked to [issue 286](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=286) of msysgit: "Case Sensitity of Directory Names", and the issue remains (again, for *directories*) even if you set `core.ignorecase` to true.

When you add "`src\Web`" (with a capital '`W`'), it won't add anything if your index already contains "`src\web`" (lowercase '`w`').

A patch was proposed but rejected:

> The folder seems to be listed as untracked because **`directory_exists_in_index()`** tries to compare the old name to the new name, and ending up not finding a match for the 
>   new folder (even though the file inside it remains tracked!).
>   A very rude patch (inlined below) was written to try to work around the issue.
>   Now... for my minimal case, this works - the directory is no longer listed as untracked. But I strongly expect this to be a BROKEN patch for at least the following reason: Case insensitive comparison should break binary searching, as the casing should return the wrong position if I had more files in the index.

```
 dir.c |    2 +-
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)

diff --git a/dir.c b/dir.c
index e05b850..c55a15c 100644
--- a/dir.c
+++ b/dir.c
@@ -444,7 +444,7 @@ static enum exist_status directory_exists_in_index(const char 
*dirname, int len)
                struct cache_entry *ce = active_cache[pos++];
                unsigned char endchar;

-               if (strncmp(ce->name, dirname, len))
+               if (strnicmp(ce->name, dirname, len))
                        break;
                endchar = ce->name[len];
                if (endchar > '/')
--
1.6.4.msysgit.0.2.gcb017.dirty
```

---

So you need to:

- change your '`Web`' into '`web`' in your working directory (filesystem)
- OR change your '`web`' into '`Web`' in the index (`git mv src/web src/Web`) in your index.

Comment: For me it's fine just knowing it's case sensitive.