# Git untracked files list is wrong

Tags: git

Somehow, git got it in its head that I have an untracked file (A directory that has been in my repository for quite some time, ~17 months). At any rate, I can't seem to convince git that this is not an untracked file. Furthermore, I can't re-add the file(s) in question. Any idea how I can fix this?

Example:

```
➜ git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   rosetta_tests/profile/tests/docking/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

I try to add the directory and re-check the status.

```
➜ git add rosetta_tests/profile/tests/docking/
➜ git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   rosetta_tests/profile/tests/docking/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Just to be sure (from the root of my source tree)

```
➜ git add .
➜ git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   rosetta_tests/profile/tests/docking/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

What is going on here? How can I convince git to fix itself?

**EDIT**

A few more details:

-The files are not in the .gitignore

-There are three tracked files in the folder in question, so it's not empty

-After even more digging, it seems something like this could arise from changing the case of a tracked folder. This, unfortunately, is not the case (pun!). The folder name has never changed case.

-Contents of the docking directory:

```
➜ ls -lA rosetta_tests/profile/tests/docking/.
total 16
-rw-r--r--  1 tim  staff  2209 Jul 17 10:47 command
-rw-r--r--  1 tim  staff   260 Jul 17 10:47 flags
drwxr-xr-x  3 tim  staff   102 Jul 17 10:47 input
```

Comment: I don't think `.gitignore` is the culprit here. Git-ignored files generally don't show up at all when running `git status`. What I'm more interested in, is if there is anything in that folder?

Comment: is the directory empty?, git can't track empty directories. git only tracks files

Comment: Should have added these to the original question. The files are not in the .gitignore and there are three tracked files in the folder in question, so it's not empty

Comment: Are you experiencing [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492186/git-lies-about-untracked-files?rq=1)?

Comment: No, the case of this directory name has never changed. I tried the mentioned fixes from this post anyways (changing both the index casing and the filesystem casing), neither worked.

Comment: can you post your .gitignore as well as a dir listing of `rosetta_tests/profile/tests/docking/`?

Comment: What's the result of `git status --untracked-files`

Comment: Do you have a file `rosetta_tests/profile/tests/docking/<unprintable-character>`? What does `ls -lA rosetta_tests/profile/tests/docking/.` show?

Comment: I don't think there are any unprintable characters. See my main post for results of the `ls` command

Comment: Which git version you're using? If it's msysgit on Windows, I'd bet that the folder case on file system does not match the case in the git index.

Answer (score 26):

I solved this by running

```
git clean -f
```

Comment: This worked for "ghost" files in untracked files list. Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

The . in the `git add .` command refers to the "current directory". So, running `git add .` will add all the files in the current directory and its subdirectories. You should ensure that you are in the correct directory before running `git add`.

`git add -A` is what you want. It will add everything.

Comment: If he were in the wrong directory, then `git status` wouldn't give him that path to the untracked file. For instance, if he were in a `foo` directory in the same directory as the `rosetta_tests` directory, `git status` would list `../rosetta_tests/profile/tests/docking/`.

Comment: This is why I mentioned I was in the root of my source tree when running 'git add .' command.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error: no case changes, no .ignore problems and the directory did contain files that I definitely wanted to keep. Adding the dir, committing, `git add -A` and other remedies did not have any effect.

I ended up deleting the directory with "git clean" and then checking out the files inside the dir again.

Here is what I did:

```
rex@sidekick> git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 10 commits.
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   app/models/xSpecific/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

At this point I made a backup copy of the "xSpecific" directory just in case. Then I made a dry run with ´git clean´ (the -n option means "dry run" and -d makes clean remove directories):

```
rex@sidekick> git clean -n -d
Would remove app/models/xSpecific/
```

After double and triple checking, I went ahead with the cleaning (the -f flag means "force" and is needed to persuade Git that you are serious. Very good design, if you ask me):

```
rex@sidekick> git clean -d -f
Removing app/models/xSpecific/

rex@sidekick> git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 10 commits.
#
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   deleted:    app/models/xSpecific/GetAddressesLog.java
#   deleted:    app/models/xSpecific/GetProductLog.java
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

So far, so good. The directory was no longer listed, but the files were of course gone too. I could have restored them from my backup, but this is what Git was made for:

```
rex@sidekick> git checkout -- app/models/xSpecific/GetAddressesLog.java
rex@sidekick> git checkout -- app/models/xSpecific/GetProductLog.java

rex@sidekick> git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 10 commits.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Time to celebrate! Actually, it would probably have been easier to just clone off a new copy of the repository and use that instead, but by doing it the hard way I learned something new :).

Comment: The `git clean` command fixed this problem for me. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

This solved the problem for me `rm .git/fs_cache`

Answer (score 2):

Same issue i got and i solved

```
git clean -f -n
```

Answer (score 1):

I had important untracked files and couldn't just run `git clean -f` as some
answers suggest.

> I try to add the directory and re-check the status.
>
> ```
> ➜ git add rosetta_tests/profile/tests/docking/
> ```

And it seems that adding a whole directory does not trigger a file recheck.

So I tried adding *specifically* one of the supposedly untracked files and it worked:

```
$ git status
On branch foo
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        important.txt
        foo/foo.java
        foo/bar.java
        foo/baz.java
        foo/qux.java

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

$ git add -- foo/foo.java
fatal: pathspec 'foo/foo.java' did not match any files

$ git status
On branch foo
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        important.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error popped up for me when `git add` failed due to a file name being too long in a sub directory.  (in my case, something in node_modules)

In this case, adding a .gitignore file with content of `*` to the node_modules folder allowed git add to run to completion.

So, pay attention to the command output of `git add .` (or -A or --all) and make sure it is not stopping prematurely due to an error.  All of my "untracked" files and folders were added successfully once the proper .gitignore was applied and I was able to commit and push my changes.

Answer (score 0):

Recreate the file or directory

```
mkdir -p rosetta_tests/profile/tests/docking/
```

And then remove it again.

```
rm -rf rosetta_tests/profile/tests/docking/
```