# Git status reports untracked on tracked files

Tags: git

Git status reports untracked files:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
# resource.enlighten/map/enlighten_test/.enlighten/__build_object__/geometry/land_9/processed/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

But we have this file at index:

```
$ git ls-tree -r HEAD |grep land_9/processed/root.pim
100644 blob 9eeca5c75dc2c945600b6e0d253a8cb8191b7e80    resource.enlighten/map/enlighten_test/.enlighten/__build_object__/geometry/land_9/processed/root.pim
```

I have checked this error appear after the first commit, that added this file.

I have tried:

1. Clone repo.
2. Clean/Checkout file (as described at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11525358/git-untracked-files-list-is-wrong) article) - after checkout the same untracked status.
3. Copy full directory resource.enlighten/ to another repo and add commit - no errors.
4. Run git fsck - no errors.

Git version 1.8.1.2.

Thank you in advance for any thoughts.

**P.S. This case is fixed in Git for Windows 1.8.3.**

Comment: Strange. Note that the untracked "file" is actually a directory, which Git doesn't track unless it has contents.

Comment: I know that the last time I ran into this problem, someone had committed two files that differed only in case in Linux. They then tried to access the repo from a Mac (case-insensitive file system).

Comment: processed/root.pim is a file.

Comment: `processed/`, which is what git is claiming is untracked is not that file.

Comment: Git doesn't process directories. There is tracked files in processed/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This case is fixed in Git for Windows 1.8.3.

Answer (score 1):

Case insensitivity on a Mac is a problem.  You might try

```
git config core.ignorecase true
```

> If true, this option enables various workarounds to enable git to work
>   better on filesystems that are not case sensitive, like FAT. For
>   example, if a directory listing finds "makefile" when git expects
>   "Makefile", git will assume it is really the same file, and continue
>   to remember it as "Makefile".