# git still shows files as untracked despite .gitignore and rm -r --cached. What did I do wrong?

Tags: git, jekyll, gitignore

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in this case with my .gitignore file, but these files keep showing up.

### Background

I'm using Jekyll to build a blog. Jekyll generates `_site` and `.sass-cache` directories when it begins serving.

I previously committed these directories before realizing I wanted to ignore them.

To be overly cautious, I added all of the following lines to my `.gitignore`:

```
##Jekyll
/_site/
_site/
_site
/.sass-cache/
.sass-cache/
.sass-cache
```

Since I knew I'd committed these files previously, I:

- Committed the updated `.gitignore` file.
- did a `git rm -r --cached .`
- deleted the `_site` and `.sass-cache` folders
- ran a `git add .` and `git status` showed that the working directory was clean

### Problem

Despite all of that, the updated .gitignore file, and verifying (I think?) that things are clean and good, whenever I run `bundle exec jekyll serve` and jekyll generates the files, I see `.sass-cache` and `_site` show up in my untracked files.

### Question

- What am I doing wrong here? Is my .gitignore formed improperly?
- How can I ensure that git never shows these directories in the untracked list?

The .gitignore in its current state [can be found here](https://github.com/SeanKilleen/seankilleen.github.io/blob/1503b5b9125914128c893211dff0d0bac9fe08a6/.gitignore).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your `.gitignore` file is currently detected as UTF-16LE encoded. Changing encoding to UTF-8 is the solution.

To fix:

- Open the .gitignore file in a text editor such as Notepad++
- Change the encoding (in np++, this is via the `Encoding` menu) to UTF-8 without BOM
- Save the file.
- Add the .gitignore file into staging
- `git commit -m "fixed ignore file"`

At this point, the ignore file should start working correctly.

Comment: Thanks! This was definitely the issue and I'll mark as correct. Just curious: How did you know that it was an encoding issue? Until I opened it in Notepad++ and checked, it wasn't apparent to me.

Comment: I first created a new .gitignore from scratch, then guessing that it can be encoding or bom, just checked the original and saw that it was UTF-16LE. An other hint was that the file is seen as a binary file and not a text file.

Comment: Great! Thank you for the context; that'll be really helpful if I run into this again (never occurred to me that it might happen).

Comment: For those who want do change encoding with `ATOM` use the `convert-file-encoding` package.